# Remove a vertex from a graph keeping shortest path distance same

Tags: algorithms, graphs, shortest-path, weighted-graphs

How could we delete an arbitrary vertex from a directed weighted graph without changing the shortest-path distance between any other pair of vertices? We are allowed to reweight the edges.

Comment: This should be pretty simple.  What have you tried?  Have you tried solving this for just a small number of nodes?

Comment: I think if there is a path from u->x->v where x is to be deleted then connecting u->v by d(u,x)+d(x,v) should solve the problem. Actually, I have 2 follow up questions on this but want to solve them by myself so did not post the entire question here. 8th question  in excercises if anyone is curious http://jeffe.cs.illinois.edu/teaching/algorithms/book/09-apsp.pdf

Comment: You should specify in your question that you're allowed to add/reweigh edges, if that's the case.

Comment: @Steven It is not mentioned in the question either. I was learning graph theory and found a bunch of interesting questions. See my previous comment for the link to the original question

Comment: But it is specified in the question... The source you linked says: "Describe an algorithm that constructs a directed graph $G' = (V \setminus \{v\}, E')$ with weighted edges, such that the shortest-path distance between any two vertices in $G'$ is equal to the shortest-path distance between the same two vertices in $G$, in $O(V^2)$ [sic] time."

Comment: @Steven Oh!My bad. Sorry, I did not notice that. By the way I am curious, are there any other ways to keep the shortest path distance same?

Comment: Certainly yes,  adding other edges

Comment: Your solution would work, but not in $O(V^2)$ since you'd first need to find the shortest path between all vertex pairs.  Try thinking about which edges get removed when you remove vertex $x$. What happens if those edges belong to a shortest path?  What can you replace them with?